# Why do these weird lines appear in my render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Applied denoiser as well, rendering in cycles on GTX1050Ti

Also why is there that weird noise just behing the rocks, like smudged kind of thing?

[image: Look at the rocks, there are those black lines on them]

Comment: Hi. Which render engine are you using? You've tagged both Cycles and the Blender Internal engine.

Comment: So sorry for that i will edit, i am using Cycles

Comment: Hello :). These look a lot like denoising artifacts. Have you tried to increase samples or turn denoising off?

Comment: yes, i took the samples up to 512, that helped a little, also tried disabling the denoiser, that made it kinda more noisy :(

Comment: Try increasing your sample count to 1000 maybe?Along with denoiser .Also what is your background?

Comment: 1000 ok.. my background is just a plane stretched out

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem

Comment: @JoeCrozier not really, my best guess is something was wrong with the lighting

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this is happening, but I have narrowed it down to your light with some basic trouble shooting.

It happens with only a lamp and the floor thus only place the problem can be. Applied the scale to the light and lines gone.

Check scaling on all your lights... and the rest of your items.

;)

Comment: just cross-checked this, did a ctrl+a and scale on all objects, but the render was still the same noisy